# query mysql date time with compare from now time and update a field on mysql

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I need to check which plant are online so I'm thinking to compare last date time update to the current time if difference is less than 15 min the plant is online otherwise is offline

I have write this in php to make a query but all row change to online or offline what I'm doing wrong?

it seams that the update is done on all row of the database not only in the selected by the first query

```
$sql = "select * from PlantData where lastUpdate > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)";
$resultt = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
//echo($resultt);
while ($roww = $resultt->fetch_array()) {
    $rowws[] = $roww;
}

foreach($rowws as &$roww) {

    $sqlupdate = "update PlantData set statusConnection = 'online'";
    mysqli_query($connection, $sqlupdate);

}

$sql2 = "select * from PlantData where lastUpdate < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)";
$resultt2 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql2);
//echo($resultt);
while ($roww2 = $resultt2->fetch_array()) {
    $rowws2[] = $roww2;
}

foreach($rowws2 as &$roww2) {

    $sqlupdate2 = "update PlantData set statusConnection = 'offline'";
    mysqli_query($connection, $sqlupdate2);

}
```

thanks for support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the query in only once

```
UPDATE PlantData 
SET 
    statusConnection = CASE
        WHEN lastUpdate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE THEN 'online'
        WHEN lastUpdate < NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE THEN 'offline'
    END;
```

Comment: I need a little modification:
I need to update with online and offline another table call plant but the date to compare with now() is in the table PlantData do you have some suggestion? Thanks

Comment: And what modifications do you need? ;Maybe make a new question

Comment: to the query that you have suggested me yesterday I don't how to write it. maybe you can help me so 
UPDATE plant SET statusConnection = CASE but here I have to check lastUpdate from another table

Comment: you can do it  like this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7d249a6eac017ee55047223d1a550528